# Use existing json file to test with Pester and TestDrive

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, pester

I have a json file which is manipulated during an automation process and I have created a unit test for it which works just fine, but I'm accessing the file system and this is for me not the way to go. Then I found out about [Pester TestDrive](https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/usage/testdrive), but I didn't understand how I can me it work in my use case.

This is my sample json file (`user.json`):

```json
{
    "name":"",
    "age": ""
}
```

Here is my function (`SetUser.ps1`):

```
function SetUser {
    param (
        $Name,
        $Age
    )

    $userFilePath = "$PSScriptRoot/user.json"
    
    $user = Get-Content $userFilePath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
    $user.name = $Name
    $user.age = $Age
}
```

This is my current test (`SetUser.Test.ps1`):

```
Describe "SetUser" {
    It "Returns expected output" {
        # Arrange
        $userFilePath = "$PSScriptRoot/user.json"
        $name = "Some Random User Name"
        $age = 30
        
        # Act
        SetUser -Name $name -Age $age

        # Assert
        $user = Get-Content $userFilePath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
        $user.name | Should -Be $name
        $user.age | Should -Be $age
    }
}
```

How can I use TestDrive to test this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a parameter `$userFilePath` to function `Set-User` so you can pass a test path. Define a default value for this parameter so you don't need to change the caller code for regular usage.

```
function SetUser {
    param (
        $Name,
        $Age,
        $userFilePath = "$PSScriptRoot/user.json"
    )
    
    $user = Get-Content $userFilePath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
    $user.name = $Name
    $user.age = $Age
}
```

Test code:

```
Describe "SetUser" {
    It "Returns expected output" {
        # Arrange
        $userFilePath = "TestDrive:/user.json"
        $name = "Some Random User Name"
        $age = 30
        
        # Act
        SetUser -Name $name -Age $age -userFilePath $userFilePath

        # Assert
        $user = Get-Content $userFilePath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
        $user.name | Should -Be $name
        $user.age | Should -Be $age
    }
}
```

Normal code:

```
SetUser -Name Foo -Age 42   # $userFilePath defaults to "$PSScriptRoot/user.json"
```

---

You may also want to add a [`Should -HaveParameter`](https://pester.dev/docs/commands/Should#haveparameter) test case to check the correct default value of parameter `-userFilePath`.